# google maps api v2 flicker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

My map code seems to cause my app to flicker/flash about every second. Anyone see anything that sticks out? It tracks where I have been with red circles. It doesn't seem to go to the zoom level I set either.

Thanks

```
 package com.direction.investor.farmsprayer;

import com.direction.investor.farmsprayer.R;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.LocationSource.OnLocationChangedListener;



import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Circle;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolygonOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

Location myLocation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




// Get back the mutable Circle

Location myLocation;

LocationManager locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria cr = new Criteria();
String provider = locationmanager.getBestProvider(cr, true);
Location location = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 200, 0, (LocationListener) this);



}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     GoogleMap mMap;
        mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);


        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(17));
     mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng((new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))));


     CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
    .center(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    circleOptions.radius(3.048); // In meters
    circleOptions.fillColor(0xffff0000);
    circleOptions.strokeWidth(0);


     mMap.addCircle(circleOptions); 


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code, you are reinitialising the map fragment every time when your `onlocationchanged` method gets called.

Decalre your map `GoogleMap mMap;` as a global variable accessible to all methods in your class. Initialise your map fragment only one time whenever your app loads and so move the below code to your `onResume()` method so that its called only once. Also after setting mMap to your map fragment, do a null check ensure that the fragment is loaded, before doing other map initialisations.

```
     mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if(mMap!=null) {
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(17));
}
```